# What is the best way to organize my local python scripts?

Tags: python

I have a bunch of useful scripts that I want to import from time to time. How to best organize them? I would want them to be on my `/home/` folder -- is that possible? Is that the best way?

On a related note, when my other scripts import my local scripts, is there a best practice to make them portable? Should I include notes in my script to alert readers / myself that I'm importing from self-written script?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you consider making a package? http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `.bashrc` you can specify the `$PYTHONSTARTUP` and `$PYTHONPATH` parameters. I have the following in my own `.bashrc`:

```
export PYTHONSTARTUP=$HOME/.config/python/pythonrc.py
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$HOME/.config/python/path
```

Note that The `.bashrc` file is for `bash` specifically. Other shells may have other files loaded at startup.

The `$PYTHONSTARTUP` script is run every time you start a python console. This is useful if you want to add tab completion for example. For example in the case I specified, whenever you run `python` from the terminal, the script `.config/python/pythonrc.py` is executed before the console starts.

You can put python packages which should be importable anywhere in the `$PYTHONPATH` you specified. So basically `$PYTHONPATH` for python has some similarities to `$PATH` for `bash`. Note this is not `$PATH`. I do not recommend messing with the `$PYTHONPATH` though. I think it is better to append the paths to `sys.path` in the `$PYTHONSTARTUP` script.

And then there is the `usercustomize` module. If there is a module named `usercustomize` **anywhere** in the path, it will be imported by **all python processes**. For `usercustomize` to work you do need to make sure that this is in your `$PYTHONPATH`. For `usercustomize` you do need to set it in `$PYTHONPATH`, but you could append more paths in `usercustomize.py` just like in `$PYTHONSTARTUP`, so you only need to add 1 more directory to the `$PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: What is the difference between $PYTHONSTARTUP and $PYTHONPATH? Also, what do you mean by `$PYTHONSTARTUP script`? On my Linux box, `pythonrc.py` does not exist. Is that something I have to create?

Comment: `$PYTHONSTARTUP` refers to a file which is executed when starting the python console. I set it to `$HOME/.config/python/pythonrc.py`. This file does not exist by default, you have to create it. You could try it out by creating this file with a `print` statement for example and then run `python`. You'll see your `print` statement is executed.